# How do I query the table in sqlalchemy when I use the reflect parameter "only=[table_name]"?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to build a flask web app that interfaces with a remote, pre-existing sql server database.

I have a successful connection, according to the output of echo='debug.'

I'm using the .reflect() "only" parameter because the database I'm connecting to has hundreds of tables. Without it, the entire database gets reflected and it runs way too slow.

```
engine = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://user:pass@server/db', echo='debug')

conn = engine.connect()
meta = MetaData(engine).reflect(schema='dbo', only=['Bookings'])
table = meta.tables['Bookings']

select_st = select([table]).where(
   table.c.ID == 'id-1234')
res = conn.execute(select_st)
for _row in res:
    print(_row)
```

The problem is that I'm getting the error:

```
    table = meta.tables['Bookings']
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tables'
```

My guess is that .tables doesn't work with the subset 'Bookings' that I've passed it because .tables calls the meta object, which it believes should be a database, not a a table.

How can I get sqlalchemy features to work with that 'only' parameter? Again, I'm building a flask web app so the solution needs to be able to interface with Base.automap.

Answer (score 1):

`.reflect()` does not return a value / returns `None`. So `meta` is `None`.
Try it like this please:

```
meta = MetaData(engine)
meta.reflect(schema='dbo', only=['Bookings'])
table = meta.tables['Bookings']
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your suggestion. But it ended up populating a KeyError instead. I spent the weekend going into a rabbit hole and while I understand flask-sqlalchemy a little more, I had to rewrite my code because initially I wasn't sure what I was doing.